# Converting an .xml file to .ggb

Tags: xml, geogebra

I accidentally saved a wrong version of my Geogebra file to my computer and ended up with a text file that appears to be xml. I did try to look in my laptop's temporary files but there wasn't anything and I ended up with a zip file with three microsoft edge pages that say they're xml. I don't know much about coding and programming languages but is there a way I could retrieve my file?

[This is the zip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgNAJ.png)

Comment: There is no XML file, only HTML files.  HTML and XML are similar, but not the same.  Both HTML and XML are text files and can be viewed with any text editor.